# Regarding 'this' keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, this

In my web page I've a `Linkbutton` with `OnClientClick` event as show below.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="dosomething(this.Text)" />
```

and I've defined the function as shown below in the head section of the web "page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dosomething(ObjCntxt)
    {
        alert(ObjCntxt.toLocaleString());
        var textval = ObjCntxt;
        alert(textval.value);            
    }
</script>
```

When i run the page and click on the `LinkButton` i'm getting the message `undefined`.

I request you all kindly solve my problem.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: You've got a problem with JavaScript and HTML, but you are showing us JavaScript and ASP. It would be easier to answer (and not require knowledge of as many domains) if you rephrased your question as "Why doesn't this ASP generate this HTML?" or "Why doesn't this HTML interact with this JavaScript in the way I expect?"

Comment: what is the value of onClientClick attribute?

Comment: I highly agree with @David; what's a `LinkButton`? I don't know those (ASP.NET-specific?) attributes. You really should show (relevant parts of) the *resulting* HTML, as that's what browsers actually get to see.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function doSomething(ObjCntxt) {
        alert(ObjCntxt); // Text
        alert(ObjCntxt.toLocaleString()); // Text
        alert(ObjCntxt.toString()); // Text

        alert(ObjCntxt.value); // undefiend
    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="doSomething(this.text);">Text</asp:LinkButton>
```

Remember, that the content of `doSomething` is JavaScript, not .NET, so you should use JavaScript members, such as `this.text` not `this.Text`

What do you expect from `ObjCntxt.value`?? Christmas gift?

Comment: The `language` attribute of `script` elements has been deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function doSomething(ObjValue) {
        alert(ObjValue); // Text
       }
</script>   

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="doSomething(this.value);">Text</asp:LinkButton>
```